# jQuery Timepicker and jQuery Datepair: How to set end time into 15mins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery timepicker and jQuery datepair

here's my html code

`<p id="timeOnlyExample">
    <input type="text" class="time start" /> to
    <input type="text" class="time end" />
</p>`

and my jQuery code

`$('#timeOnlyExample .time').timepicker({
    'showDuration': true,
    'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
});`

`var timeOnlyExampleEl = document.getElementById('timeOnlyExample');
var timeOnlyDatepair = new Datepair(timeOnlyExampleEl);`

So the output of this code is: for example I choose 1:00am in the time start and the output of time end is 2:00pm so the time interval is 1 hour.

But I want to do is when I choose 1:00am in the time start I want the output in the time end is 1:15am 15 mins interval. I'm searching right now for the solution but I think there is someone who can help me in this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use ***interval*** option.

```
$('#timeOnlyExample .time').timepicker({
    'showDuration': true,
    'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
    'interval': 15 // 15 minutes
});
```

More details at : http://timepicker.co/options/

You should initialize the datepair with ***defaultTimeDelta*** .

```
var timeOnlyDatepair = new Datepair(timeOnlyExampleEl, {
  'defaultTimeDelta': 15*60*1000 // milliseconds
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the output of this is still the same of my example yes I can choose in the time start : for example 1:00am, 1:15am , 1:30am, and 1:45am. But  when I choose 1:00am in the time start and the output of the time end is 2:00am still 1 hour when the time is in the time end.

Comment: the Default is 1hour interval, I can't set the default is in 15min interval

Answer (score 1):

try adding 'step' :15,

```
$('#timeOnlyExample.time').timepicker({
        'step' :15,
        'showDuration': true,
        'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
    });
```

Comment: I solved it already ^_^ I edit the Datepair.js I edit the defaultTimeDelta: 3600000 into defaultTimeDelta: 900000

Comment: Thanks I will also edit the source code. Thanks for the tip!